# Practical use of BCC:

Tags: email

I don't have the permission to send emails to outlook groups. I can, however, expand the groups and send the email to individual email addresses.
However this causes a large amount of cluttering and 'Noise' especially in the CC: field.

Is it acceptable to put the groups in the CC: (knowing that I couldn't send to the group) and include the individual email addresses in the BCC: field?

For example:

```
To: John expense accountant
CC: Finance Group               -- I dont have permission to send to finance group
BCC: Jim receivable accountant, Jake payable accountant
```

Finance group includes all of John, Jim and Jake.

It would generate an email saying that the message failed sendiong to the group as I dont have permission but it would look like that I can send.

Is this acceptable in the sake of practicability?

Comment: I'd suggest talking to your manager and explaining the difficulties that your silly IT policies are having on your ability to do your job, and getting them to fix the underlying cause.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Actually we are a subsidiary of a larger company and IT is managed by it. Requests have always been "a quest for justification" for them. A simple password reset takes between 2 to 3 hours with some 15 emails back and forth.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the list? Is it possible that there is another address that you should be using other than one that goes to an entire department?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/99722/email-etiquette-carbon-copies-and-blind-carbon-copies/99751#99751

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email Etiquette: Carbon Copies and Blind Carbon Copies](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/99722/email-etiquette-carbon-copies-and-blind-carbon-copies)

Comment: You don't have permission to send emails to an Outlook group, so you shouldn't send mails to an outlook group. Someone placed that restriction for a reason, so you shouldn't just circumvent it by copying individual addresses (and much worse, putting them in bcc). If it is genuinely required for you to send mails to outlook groups to do your job, get that restriction lifted and then send mails to the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest do not do that. You will be able to send the email you want but you can’t know if the effect is what you expect. 
People use filters to keep their inbox in order and they most probably have filters based on groups. Your email will not go where they will expect to find based on their filters and **they** will start asking help desk what’s wrong with the filters. So you will create more noise than you what you want to avoid. There are other weird cases too like people expecting you to have other rights too if they think you can email that list which you don’t.

Comment: "they most probably have filters based on groups" - relying on the assumption that an Outlook e-mail sent to a group will actually have that group in its recipient field is problematic in itself. Just opening a group to check who is inside will remove the group reference in Outlook, as far as I have have seen. So, people using such filters will probably miss quite a few e-mails rather than just the one that use the group in the Bcc field.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: iirc if you tap on the group only it expands. Otherwise it keeps it. But in any case I don’t think assuming all recipients use Outlook is also valid

Comment: It's the *sender* whose e-mail client matters, not the recipient. Also, depending on the organization, it can be highly likely that everyone uses the same e-mail client.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: why is it the sender only? Also I am sure there are (small) organizations that have only one client. I don’t have concrete data if the majority is a mixed set of clients or not in any case. But my answer should apply to any similar use of bcc regardless of that.

Comment: Because recipients cannot retroactively change what is in the *To* or *Cc* field of an e-mail. If the *sender* expands the list in one of these fields before sending the mail, though, Outlook will warn that the [expanded list cannot be collapsed again](https://d2d42mpnbqmzj3.cloudfront.net/images/stories/doc-outlook/doc-merge-distribution-list/doc-merge-distribution-list-3.png), and all recipients will see the full set of list members. As for using different e-mail clients, I thought homogenous systems are most common in organizations large enough to install machines systematically, ...

Comment: ... rather than having everyone set up their own machine. As I said, this very much depends on the organization, and whether an "all-round-solution" for the topic of e-mails/contacts/calendars such as MS Exchange is used organization-widely.

Comment: @O.r.mapper: what matters is which rule in the client applies to the email received. If the recipient has a different filter for the group and emails send directly to them then the email will end up probably in the wrong folder. As for the homogeneous systems this depends on the department. Some want Mac and others Windows. An MS exchange does not mean the recipient on a Mac would open it in Outlook for Mac

Comment: "If the recipient has a different filter for the group and emails send directly to them" - I got that, but my point is that such a filter is destined to fail all the time for various reasons. One of them is that e.g. Outlook makes it so easy to inadvertently replace a group with a list of its members. You're right about the clients in cases where there is much contact between departments with so different preferences.